# Construct an example: irreducible algebraic variety induces a reducible germ.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This is another exercise of Daniel Huybrechts' book "Complex Geometry An Introduction". The question asks to construct examples of:
1. Reducible variety induces an irreducible germ.
2. Irreducible variety induces a reducible germ.

For #1, I found that a variety $X=\{0, 1\}$ of two single points is reducible while at either point it induces an irreducible germ.

For #2, can any one give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cusp $y^2=x^2+x^3$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is irreducible but has a reducible germ at the origin $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you Georges. Actually I worked on this example for hours but didn't know how to show the germ is reducible. Could you give me the equation that defines the reducible variety (that induces the same germ)?

Comment: The equations of the two irreducible components of the germ of the curve at $(0,0)$ are $y=\pm x\sqrt {1+x}$  for $\vert x\vert \lt 1$

Comment: Thanks I was thinking but always thought $\sqrt{1+x}$ is not well defined but now I realized it is since $1+x$ is not $0$.